# flutter print value of variable by passing variable

Tags: flutter, variables, dart

I am trying get value of variable.
sample is below.

```
var X=10 ;
var Y="X" ;
//print(Y) ;
//how i can get print value of Y as 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var X= 10;
var Y= X;
// print(Y) ;
// just remove the quote, this will now print 10
```

Comment: thats ok.  but when i am using visual foxpro, in that we can get value of Y by using    &Y     Is there any facility like this ?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.